# How to avoid down cast when using polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, static-cast

Consider the following design:

```
class RawDataBase
{
private:    
    std::string data;
};

class RawDataA : public RawDataBase
{
private:    
    int spec_data_for_a1;
    int spec_data_for_a2;
};

class RawDataB : public RawDataBase
{
private:    
    int spec_data__for_b;
};

class MessageBase
{
private:    
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    virtual void Decode(RawDataBase *raw)
    {
        // extract x,y,z from raw.data
    }
};

class MessageA : public MessageBase
{
private:    
    int spec_data_for_a1;
    int spec_data_for_a2;
public:
    /* Here raw must be RawDataA*/
    virtual void Decode(RawDataBase *raw)
    {
        MessageBase::Decode(raw);
        RawDataA raw_data = static_cast<RawDataA*>(raw);
        // extract spec_data_for_a1, spec_data_for_a2 from raw_data
    }
};

class MessageB : public MessageBase
{
private:    
    int spec_data__for_b;
public:
    /* Here raw must be RawDataB*/
    virtual void Decode(RawDataBase *raw)
    {
        MessageBase::Decode(raw);
        RawDataB raw_data = static_cast<RawDataB*>(raw);
        // extract spec_data__for_b from raw_data       
    }
};
```

I have a design issue while decoding `RawData` to `Message`.

There are two types of `RawData` (`RawDataA` & `RawDataB`). `RawDataA` will be decoded as `MessageA`, while `RawDataB` will be decoded as `MessageB`. Both of `RawDataA` and `RawDataB` shared some common data, so `RawDataBase` was created as a base class.
Same goes for `MessageA` and `MessageB` derived from `MessageBase`.

Then, one virtual `Decode` function is added into `MessageBase`, taking a `RawDataBase` object as parameter. But there is some problem in `MessageA`
 and `MessageB`. For `MessageA`, the parameters actually should always be `RawDataA`, so a down cast has to been done here. But someone says there must be some design issue when a down cast has to been used in code.

So my question is how to design the code here to avoid down cast?

Thanks!

Comment: `template` seems better than inheritance here to factorize code.

Comment: do you also mean CRTP ? or another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Not necessary CRTP, a simple template class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid down cast here:

```
class MessageA : public MessageBase {
    virtual void Decode(RawDataBase *raw) { ...}
}
```

Your code must become something like that:

```
class MessageA : public MessageBase {
    virtual void Decode(RawDataA *raw) { ...}
}
```

Which means `MessageBase` must somehow become:

```
class MessageBase {
    virtual void Decode(RawDataA *raw){...}
}
```

This can be done using templates like this:

```
class RawDataBase { /* ... */ };
class RawDataA : public RawDataBase { /* ... */ }; 
class RawDataB : public RawDataBase { /* ... */ };

template<typename T>
class MessageBase {

    using RawDataType = T;

    // ...

    virtual void Decode(RawDataType *raw){/* ... */}

    // ...

};

class MessageA : public MessageBase<RawDataTypeA> {
    // ...

    virtual void Decode(RawDataType *raw){/* ... */}

    // ...
};

class MessageB : public MessageBase<RawDataTypeB> {
    // ...

    virtual void Decode(RawDataType *raw){/* ... */}

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Cool!! This fixed my issue:-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is not CRTP, it would be for `class Derived : public Base<Derived>`. Here it is a simple inheritance of template class.

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right, my bad. I edited my answer. Thx :)